# How to get current date from server on jsp or in Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

i want to get date from server i have tried below code but takes date from current system
, as i have run my application on different system it gives different result,because system date is different.

My code is:

```
String date = "yyyy-MM-dd"; 
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();     
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(date);       
System.out.println("Today Date = "+dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

so i am expecting the resulting date from server, not from system as different system has different dates.

Comment: if you are running your system on localhost, then your system itself behave like server.

Comment: so whenever my application is hosted, then new Date() will gives me server date whatever system date is..right coders..

Comment: I don't even know what you're asking: all Java/JSP runs on the server. If you get the date you're already getting the date on the server. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @Dave Newton as shown in above code last line will print today's date which is on system. but if i changed system date,next time it will take changed date so i want to take current world clock date whatever the system date is...is it possible as i am running my application on localhost..

Comment: I have no idea where you're running your application.

Comment: @Dave are you getting my question or not...

Comment: @Aniket No, because you're not being precise. *I* have no way of knowing where you're running your application. If you get a timestamp in a JSP or servlet, you're getting the timestamp from whatever system that JSP or servlet is running on, period. If the app is running on machine A, and I'm accessing it from machine B, I'll get machine A's timestamp. If I'm running the app on machine A, and accessing it from machine A, I'll get machine A's timestamp. If you runn the app on the same machine you browse from, of course you'd get a different time if you change the time--you changed the time.

Comment: @Dave i have one issue if i hosted my application on server where it is exactly take date (my above code) from server or from current system....

Comment: @Aniket I don't know what else to tell you: JSP (which compiles to a servlet) **takes the date from the system it is running on**. Period. That's just the way it works. If you're claiming you change your *local* time, and you see a difference in an app *running on a different machine*, I don't believe it. If you're running the app *on the same machine you've changed the date on*, then of *course* you'll see it change. I don't understand where the communication barrier is here.

Comment: i will give you live example "after each comment from anyone the name of person who comment and time (as at the end of above comment "Dave Newton 1 hour ago")will be displayed, if you take cursor over the time  it shows date of comment("2012-12-17"), if i am changed the date of my system("like 2012-12-31") , and give one more comment and check the date it will shows the date "2012-12-17" not "2012-12-31" as you told me it has to get current system date which is "2012-12-31" so why this is showing the date "2012-12-17" other than system date, here stack overflow not taken my system date..why??

Comment: @Aniket Why would SO use *your* system's time? Is SO running on *your* machine?!

Comment: @Dave exactly as if i deploy my application on server where it takes current(today's) date from my system or anywhere else..????  and another question is from where SO takes date??

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. SO likely takes its date from the machine SO runs on. Are you asking for the server to take the date from *your* machine? How would it do that without your machine telling the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

This would help you.
If you want the formatted date then

```
Date d1 = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat('MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm AM');
String formattedDate = df.format(d1);
```

Comment: arvin i have already told u Date d1 = new Date(); will gives current system date, i need server date whatever the system date is.

Comment: @Aniket That sentence makes no sense without any context: the code is running on the server; the server has a system date. What date do you think you're looking for?

Comment: @Dave Newton as shown in above code last line will print today's date which is on system. but if i changed system date,next time it will take changed date so i want to take current world clock date whatever the system date is...is it possible as i am running my application on localhost..

Answer (score 1):

```
<strong>Server Time&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><label id="timelable"></label>


<script type="text/javascript">
        var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 1000);
        var jsVar=  <%=java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()%>;
        var timeZoneOffset=<%=java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis())%>;

        jsVar=jsVar+timeZoneOffset;
        function myTimer() {
        jsVar=jsVar+1000;
        var d = new Date(jsVar);
        var t=d.toUTCString();
    document.getElementById("timelable").innerHTML = t;
}

        </script>
```

now you will see the server time running in you jsp.